# problem with open-MPI using Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, libraries

I updated Ubuntu from 10.04 to 12.04 and installed open-mpi1.6.1 from the site www.open-mpi.org using the g95 compiler (because it is necessary to do so in order to run the chimere air pollution model). 
Two years ago I did the same thing using Ubuntu 10.04 and open-mpi1.4.1 without any problem. 
Now the program always stops with:

```
/opt/openmpi-1.6.1-g95/bin/mpif90 -o chimere.e -I/usr/local/include -I/include -cpp -O3  -DG95 -fno-second-underscore -i4  -DMPI -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-huge \
                chimere.o integrun.o master_message_subs.o master_locvalues.o \
                chimere_common.o message_defs.o chimere_consts.o chimere_params.o \
                -L.  -linitio -ltools -lmodel -ltools -liso -L/usr/local/lib -lnetcdf -L/lib -L/opt/openmpi-1.6.1-g95/lib/

ld: chimere.o: undefined reference to symbol 'mpi_null_delete_fn_'

ld: note: 'mpi_null_delete_fn_' is defined in DSO /opt/openmpi-1.6.1-g95/lib/libmpi.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line

/opt/openmpi-1.6.1-g95/lib/libmpi.so.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation

make: *** [chimere] Error 1
```

I set links (ln -s) of the open-mpi libraries to `/usr/lib` and

```
objdump -T /usr/lib/libmpi.so.1 

indicates mpi_null_delete_fn and mpi_null_delete_fn_
```

http://pastebin.com/K08EnJAF describes a similar problem.

Does anybody has an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Add `-lmpi` to your call.

You specified where the correct library is located, but you didn't tell your linker to link it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added -lmpi but the error remains.

Comment: He is using `mpif90`, which already takes care of linking against `libmpi`, so adding `-lmpi` has no effect.